# How to Risk and Return using Carhart 4 factor model

Tags: risk-models, fama-french, abnormal-returns

I have to calculate firm risk and return for a group of firms. I have firm CUSIPs. I also have access to CRSP data from WRDS. Can someone explain to me how I can use CRSP and data from Ken French’s online data library to calculate firm risk and return measures? If there is a Stata code for this, it would be particularly useful. If there is some online source that I can use, please point me in that direction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you made an attempt with your own code?

Comment: @amdopt - I have merged the CRSP daily data with the data from French's data library using the date stamp. I am not sure, if I need to now run regression for each observation separately or I need to create a window for 252 trading days and run then run regressions.